# Integrating CakeDC plugin in a CakePHP (2.5.1) application

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakedc

I am new in CakePHP, developing a web application. I have implemented login, registration (including recaptcha) and other data entry options for the application. Now, i need to add an Admin Panel and option of email confirmation (to confirm registration) to the existing application. I have found a plugin - CakeDC/users , and trying to integrate it with the application. After installing and uploading the files, it shows Add User, Login options. when I add a user, it shows following error:

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.email_verified' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`id` FROM `database`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`email_verified` = 0 AND `User`.`email_token_expires` < '2016-07-26 09:54:14' GROUP BY `User`.`id`
```

Could anyone tell me what went wrong here ? which tables need to be created to my existing database for integrating the plugin ? I could not find any clear instruction in the documentation of CakeDC/Users.

The problem is the features that i implemented before are not working now. it only shows plugin features (Add User, Login etc.) which I already implemented. It seems all my application features are overridden by the plugin. Is it because of admin routing ? How should i set the routing for CakeDC/users admin plugin ? I have UsersController(.php) in my application where i implemented add, login, edit, delete functions. In the CakeDC/Users plugin, it also has a UsersController where add, login etc. functions are implemented. Does it creating any conflict ?

I need to integrate an Admin Panel for the user management and feature of email confirmation (to confirm registration) to my existing application, not overriding its features. Is there any plugin to do so ? or I have to implement it myself ? Any other plugins are also acceptable if it suits with my above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you missed something with the routing. Therefore cakephp tries to look for a controller, where you actually call a method.
Have you added the routes statement into your bootstrap.php where you load the plugin?

```
CakePlugin::load('Users', array(
'routes' => true
));
```

Try to remove all the created controllers and methods and check the routs.php file inside the Plugin/Users/Config folder if you added the routes like mentioned above.

**As stated in my last Comment the sql of the users table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
   `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
   `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `password` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
   `password_token` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
   `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `email_verified` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `email_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `email_token_expires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `tos` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `last_action` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `is_admin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `role` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
   `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`), ADD KEY `BY_USERNAME` (`username`), ADD KEY `BY_EMAIL` (`email`);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added the routes statements as you mentioned, and errors are disappeared now. But, it seems, my application features that i implemented before are overridden by this plugin. Now it is showing its own features like Add User, Login etc. which i already implemented. I could not find any clear documentation for integrating Email Confirmation and Admin Panel features with the existing application. Do you have any ?

Comment: They have a documentation for each of their releases (i.e cake 1, 2, 3) on their github.
I guess the extension you are looking for is explained here:
[extension docs](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/2.x/Docs/Documentation/Extending-the-Plugin.md)
The link to the general documentation:
[general docs](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/2.x/Docs/Home.md)
As far as the email confirmation is concerned, if you talk about registration, this is already implemented in the plugin. About the admin panel - I don't know. Hope this helps

Comment: in the documentation, there is no clear explanation about which database tables need to be created. i am getting here database error as well. Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.email_verified' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`id` FROM `database`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`email_verified` = 0 AND `User`.`email_token_expires` < '2016-07-26 09:54:14' GROUP BY `User`.`id`. do you have any idea which tables should be created to my existing database ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no documentation about this. At least as far as I am aware. Normally you´d just execute this statement in your console `bin/cake migrations migrate -p CakeDC/Users` to create the neccessary database tables. But as I understand it you already created a table. I'll add the sql of the users table in my answer. Then you can check what you still need and add it.

Comment: in /app/plugin/Users/Controller/ , there are two controllers -  UsersAppController.php and UsersController.php. did you mean these two controllers should be removed ? in that case, how routing should be configured ? i already added the route statement that you mentioned in /app/config/bootstrap.php

Comment: regarding the table, i already have a database table 'users' which is part of my application. it has username and password fields. Now, for the plugin, should i create another users table ? or should i add the additional fields that above mentioned table has ?

Comment: And, if i want to use only admin panel of the plugin, what would be the routing configuration ?

Comment: I think you would have the least configuration effort if you´d just add the  missing fields to your users table and leave the Controllers generated by the plugin and use the extension docs I mentioned in a comment above to extend the controllers with the functionality you need

Comment: you mean i should delete the controllers of the plugin ?

Comment: No. I mean that you should keep the controllers and extend them like specified [here](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/2.x/Docs/Documentation/Extending-the-Plugin.md)